# Multiplication in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data in the following format:

[image: I want implement this in SQL]

Calculation is as follows:

- Category values are known in prior
- $U13=Q13-$T$13, $U14=Q14-$T$13 and so on.. For c1 cell value T13 remains constant.
- SUM_C is sum of all C columns (Horizontal sum)

Also number of categories will not be known in prior. How to implement the same in SQL?

Comment: What DBMS are you using ?

Comment: what do you want to "implement" in SQL exactly ? `SELECT c1*c2*c3*c4*c5 FROM MyTable` ? or create a calculated column ? (which will look like pretty much the previous code)

Comment: Using SQL Server.

Comment: @Pac0 Category values are known in prior and all the c columns are calculated columns.

Answer (score 1):

You want to reference the first value of `category2_numbers_r` in every row. Use `FIRST_VALUE` for this. As to adding calculated values, I suggest you calculate the separate values first and then use this result as a subquery.

```
with data as
(
  select
    category1,
    category2_numbers,
    category2_numbers_r, 
    category2_numbers - first_value(category2_numbers_r) over (order by category1) as c1,
    ... as c2,
    ... as c3,
    ... as c4,
    ... as c5
  from mytable
)
select
  category1,
  category2_numbers,
  category2_numbers_r,
  c1, c2, c3, c4, c5,
  c1 + c2 + c3 + c4 + c5 as sum_c
from data
order by category1;
```

Comment: How to get the second value for c2 ?
first_value() is  direct function but how to achieve for second one?

Comment: Also number of categories will not be known in prior then how to implement the same? i.e. dynamic c columns

Comment: Ah, you haven't explained the formulas for c2, c3 etc., but I see now you want calculations based on the 2nd, 3rd, ... row. In standard SQL you could use `NTH_VALUE` for this, but SQL Server doesn't feature this. Anyway, as you say now that the number of categories is not fixed, you cannot write a query for this, as SQL queries have fixed columns. SQL is not made for what you want, so use it to get the raw data in rows and use your app to transfer it to a dynamic number of columns and do your spreadsheet calculations there.

Comment: True that SQL one cannot write a query for this, as SQL queries have fixed columns. Anyways works for fixed one. As of now problem is solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume your table is called MyTable that has all the other columns but SUM_C and C1

Something like this should work :

```
-- let's get your "fixed" value $T$13

declare @t13 int;
-- I don't know the exact criteria that makes T13 different from others, use the criteria in the "WHERE" clause below
SET @t13 = (SELECT TOP(1) Category2_Numbers_R FROM MyTable Where Category1 = 'A')

SELECT 
   Category1, Category2, Category2_Numbers, Category1_R, Category2_R, Category2_Numbers_R ,
   Category2_Numbers - @t13 as 'c1', -- Here is your column 'c1'
   c2, c3, c4, c5,
   Category2_Numbers - @t13 + c2 + c3 + c4 + c5 as 'SUM_C' -- Here is your column 'SUM_C'
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: How to implement if number of categories are unknown in prior ? i.e. dynamic c columns

Comment: @Keval that would be a quite different answer (and thus, you should post a different question)

Comment: Sure No problem. As of now this works. Thank for helping!